# System.AccessViolationException. Attempted to read or write into protected memory

Tags: c#, access-violation

I know that the same question has been discussed.
I’m using .dll library (originally written on C++, calling convention is stdcall). Function description that I need is following:

```
function EKSIS_COM_Read(aPortName: PAnsiChar; aPortSpeed: Integer; aID: Integer; aMem: AnsiChar; aAddr: Word; aData: PByte; aCount: Word): Boolean;
bool EKSIS_COM_Read(char[] aPortName, int aPortSpeed, int aID, char aMem, WORD aAddr, BYTE aData, WORD aCount);
```

The description of arguments :

```
aPortName – com-port (example «COM2»);
aPortSpeed –data rate;
aID –device address;
aMem – memory type (I,R,F);
aAddr –register address;
aData – a pointer to the memory address where the reading will be held;
aCount – the number of bytes read.
```

In VS 2013 using c# I wrote the following:

```
[DllImport("EksisExchange.dll", EntryPoint = "EKSIS_COM_Read", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern bool Read(char[] aPortName, int aPortSpeed, int aID, char aMem, ushort aAddr, ref float aData,
   ushort aCount);
```

But sometimes during simulation I have eror:

> System.AccessViolationException. Attempted to read or write into protected memory.

Why it is happening? And why does it occur only sometimes?

Comment: It is highly improbable that the C++ function is `char aPortName`, because that is a *single* char, not a string.

Comment: Post the function signature from the .h file if you have it.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote incorrect.. in my code it is char[]...
Unfortunately, I don't have it..

Comment: then we can't be sure the signature is right. The `BYTE aData` is a single byte of data, not surely a reference to the data. And there are some errors: you need to pass a zero terminated ANSI string, not a `char[]` as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
[DllImport("EksisExchange.dll", EntryPoint = "EKSIS_COM_Read", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern bool Read(string aPortName, int aPortSpeed, int aID, char aMem, ushort aAddr, byte[] aData, ushort aCount);
```

You must pass an ANSI, null terminated string to the function. The easiest thing is to pass a string and let the marshaler do the work. The same for `aMem`

`aData` is the buffer where the data will be read. It must be a buffer, for example a `byte[]`. You create it **before** calling the method. You put the size of the buffer in the `aCount`.

That signature should be used with something like:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
bool res = Read("COM1", 19200, 1, 'I', 123, buffer, (ushort)buffer.Length);
```

**Note that this signature is illogical: there is no place where the method can return how many bytes it did read**